# How would I alter my code to print out how many answers they got right or wrong?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need this program to print out the number of guesses you got right and wrong. I have a dictionary (called ccdict) of cities and countries, e.g. "United Kingdom":"London".  This is the code:

```
def choices (Correct):
    list=[Correct]
    f=0
    cities=ccdict.values()
    while f + 1<5:
        f=f+1
        list.append(cities[random.randint(0, len(cities))])
    list.sort()
    return list


countries = ccdict.keys()
randcountry = countries[random.randint(0, len(countries))]
print "What is the capital of " + randcountry + "?"
print "If you want to stop this game, type 'exit'"
randlist = choices(ccdict[randcountry])

for i in range(0,5):
        print str(i+1) + " - " + randlist[i]

input=raw_input("Give me the number of the city that you think is the capital of " + randcountry + " ")

if input == "exit":                               
    print "Now exiting game!" + sys.exit()       

elif  randlist[int(input)-1] == ccdict[randcountry]:
    print "Correct"

else:
    print "WRONG! The capital of " + randcountry + " is " + ccdict[randcountry]
```

Comment: you could use random.choice instead of randint

Comment: this `if input == '6':` isn't doing anything

Comment: I don't see anything "urgent" about this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your `int()` until *after* your `if` test:

```
input = raw_input("Give me the number of the city that you think is the capital of " + randcountry + " ")

if input == "exit":
    print "Now exiting game!"
    sys.exit()

elif  randlist[int(input) - 1] == ccdict[randcountry]:
    print "Correct"
```

Note how the above version only converts `input` to an integer at the last minute.

Comment: Martijn Pieters, thanks but this is the error that come up:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Cities.py", line 221, in <module>
    print str(i+1) + " - " + randlist[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That is not code you have in your question; clearly `i` is an integer number that is too large for the `randlist` length.

Comment: Sorry I had a different code here than in the other place... I fixed it now! Thanks! You are the best! BTW, is there a way to make this run in an infinite loop until I type exit?

Comment: Sure, put a `while True:` loop around the whole thing.

Comment: How could you print out the number of guesses you got right or wrong?